# Automatic snap photo in Card.io SDK iOS

Tags: ios, card.io

I am using [Card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) which is used for detecting credits cards and fetching its data. In my application i use this SDK for detecting any card not only the credit card, and this SDK recognise them perfectly, i don't care about credit card info i'm just want to detect if there is a card in front of the camera. when there is a card in front the camera the card will be surrounded by a green box and the rest of the camera UI will be blurred. The SDK automatically fetch the the credit card info it was a valid credit card and take them out and returned by the delegate.

What i want is: can i make the camera takes a photo automatically whenever there is a card detected ( credit card or ID or any other type of card ) i mean when the green box is fully drawn.

i don't want the user to press ( snap photo ) button i just want to be captured automatic.

Comment: Have you achieved this matter ? I m also looking for same. Please post comment/answer if any tips you have found.

Comment: @SolidSoft No , I didn't continue in this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. Sorry, we do not plan to expose that functionality.